# Gson custom deserializer deriving type of one field from another

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON structure where objects are basically unions - a discriminator field determines the type of the object, and each type has custom properties. As an example, imagine an Animal structure:

```
{
  animals: [
    {
      species: 'DOG',
      data: {
        buriedBones: 8
      }
    },
    {
      species: 'CAT',
      data: {
        hasEvilPlan: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

On the Java side, I'd like this to be represented by a class with the `species` discriminator enum and a `data` member, which can be either a CatData or a DogData, so something like:

```
enum Species {DOG, CAT}

abstract class Data {}
class DogData extends Data {
  int buriedBones;
}
class CatData extends Data {
  boolean hasEvilPlan;
}

public class Animal {
  public Species species;
  public Data data;
}
```

This means that when serializing, I don't really need to do anything special, but when deserializing, I need to read the `species` value and from it determine the class of the Data object (`DogData.class` or `CatData.class`), and then deserialize the data as that class and put it in the `data` field.

For this I've written a custom type adapter which uses annotations to supply a map of discriminator->data class, and it works, but I'm not quite happy. I can get the JSON tree, find the `species` value and from it the data class, but I can't find a clever way to deserialize only the `data` field using the specific class, while leaving everything else to the default behaviour. The only solution I've found so far is to remove the `data` property from the JSON tree, call the delegate adapter (which results in `animal.data` being `null`) and then manually use reflection to set the data field:

```
discriminator = "species";
...
@Override
public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
  JsonObject tree = treeAdapter.read(in).getAsJsonObject();

  // look up class from map of "DOG"->DogData.class etc
  Type dataType = getDataType(tree.get(discriminator).getAsString()); 
  tree.remove("data");
  T result = delegate.fromJsonTree(tree); // Creates an Animal with data = null

  Field field = result.getClass().getField("data");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(result, gson.fromJson(data, dataType)); // Create DogData or CatData and assign it to animal.data afterwards

  return result;
```

I'd rather not have to resort to manual reflection, but I can't find a way to use the delegate adapter, but tell it "when you reach the `data` field, please use class `DogData.class` to deserialize it". 
Note that I could of course write a TypeAdapter specifically for `Animal` which simply does `return new Animal(Species.valueOf(species), gson.fromJson(data, dataClass))`, but what I need is a generic adapter that can be used on various classes using this pattern, and where any other properties in the class are deserialized the default way.

I also know that if the classes that use this pattern would be generic, as in `Animal<D extends Data>`, I could probably deserialize them using a `TypeToken<Animal<DogData>>`, but that also puts unnecessary constraints on the data model. Again, what I'm after is a way to *only* override one specific field by telling GSON to use a specific class, derived from another field, to deserialize it, but then handle all other deserialization automatically (so that e.g. a property like `animal.nrLegs` would be preserved). Is there a clever way I missed?